# How can i parse a json that contains Geo-coordinates in android kotlin?

Tags: android, json, kotlin

i have this object in a Json file and i succeded at parsing many objects but i couldn't parse this one :

```
"location": "SRID=4326;POINT (101.167692 -0.011863)"
```

Comment: Hi, Huehendry you need to get the lat long from this string value right?

If yes and the string format is fixed then we can get the value by using split the string by white spaces

Comment: yes i know but my api does this so yeah cannot change it directly

Comment: Yes but you can get the whole string value using the location key from your JSON file and where ever needed you can split and get the value from desire index